# How to return an Arrray from VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to save the result of a function which compares two data sets and saves any identical numbers in an array but when I use the function I only get  one number which is returned when there are more than one identical number. I tried <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd> for array formula but the result was the same.

```
Set 1   Set 2    Result
278       278    56
778       778    56
56       1223    56
946        56    56
```

```vb
Function trials(number As Range, numbe As Range)
    Dim c As Range
    Dim savearray() As Variant
    Dim d As Long
    Dim e As Range

    For Each c In Range("a3:a6")
        For Each e In Range("c3:c6")
            If c.Value = e.Value Then
                ReDim Preserve savearray(d)
                savearray(d) = c.Value
                d = d + 1
                trials = savearray
            End If
        Next e
    Next c
End Function
```

Comment: What is the point of having a function which doesn't depend on its input (`number` and `numbe` in this case)?

Comment: `trials = Application.Transpose(savearray)`  and select the whole output range to enter the formula

Answer (score 0):

I can see these problems with your code:

1. What John Coleman mentioned - `number` and `numbe` should be used as arguments. I would advise some more verbose names like `rng1` and `rng2`
2. What Tim Williams said and what causes your problem is that the function returns a one-dimensional array that by default provides output in multiple cells of one row. You need to transpose array to be able to present results in multiple cells of one column using `trials = Application.Transpose(savearray)` instead of `trials = savearray`.
3. Code from point 2. should be put before `End function`, not within a loop. You want to pass a result to function only once.

On top of this, why many people can't get it to work is that you must first select output cells and then enter formula and press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>ENTER</kbd>, not drag array formula from one cell to other cells.

```
Function trials(number As Range, numbe As Range)

    Dim c As Range, e As Range
    Dim savearray() As Variant
    Dim d As Long

    For Each c In number
        For Each e In numbe
            If c.Value = e.Value Then
                ReDim Preserve savearray(d)
                savearray(d) = c.Value
                d = d + 1
            End If
        Next e
    Next c

    trials = Application.Transpose(savearray)

End Function
```

Comment: Thank you all for your advice .I have managed to return the duplicate entries in multiples cells  in a column by changing the variables declared from  Dim c As Range, e As Range to Dim c ,e As Variant and locking  upper end of the  range of set 1 and set 2 e.g trials (A1:$A$4,B1:$B$4).